# Series (?) of scifi stories about an alien race going through iterations of evolution and near extinction

Tags: story-identification

I very distinctly recall reading a scifi story as a child, possibly a series of stories. Humans land in a solar system and meet a race of aliens that, if I recall correctly, evolve very quickly, and have a cast based racial split; there are technicians, warriors and so on. The race for some reason overpopulates their own solar system and keeps killing itself mostly off, resetting the cycle. They cannot leave their solar system (they have no FTL technology, but the humans do) and are very interested in learning how to.

Some story points I remember, all of them being developments/revelations, so obviously spoilers:

> The humans arrive in two big ships, and they lose one of the ships due to one of the servant races breeding uncontrollably in the vents. The aliens are surprised that the humans don't periodically vent their air to prevent things like that.

> The aliens have sent (one or multiple) solar sail 'powered' ships with members of their race in cryosleep to other planets, but none have reached them yet.

Near finale spoilers I remember:

> The humans intercept one of the ancient solar ships and discover that the aliens didn't send scientists but warriors

> The humans flee and blockade the solar system because they realize the race is only interested in escaping their solar system in order to breed forever and flood the galaxy. They can do that because even though the aliens have further advanced tech, because the exit jump point from the aliens solar system (or something like that) is inside a gas giant/solar corona/whatever that makes any ships that emerge from their system have their shields down and be easy prey to the humans.

The story ends with:

> The humans took some of the aliens (just one ?) with them, and the alien either monologues to itself or to another one that humans will forever keep them trapped, but that humanity as a race will some day through calamity, war, politics or whatever stop bothering, and their race will eventually escape.

It bothered me for years that I couldn't remember the name of the story because I would love to read it again.

Comment: *Mote in God's Eye* by Niven and Pournelle.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mote_in_God%27s_Eye) has a decent summary of the story covering all the details OP remembers.

Comment: @user14111 indeed! Copy-paste mistake, my bad, thanks for the fix :)

Comment: I have gone back and added more to my answer in the linked question, to make it more useful.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! That is indeed the story I was looking for, and the reference (on the linked Wikipedia article) to the [War World Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_World) is why I was confused as to whether it was a single book or series. It's hard to believe I missed this story when I searched on my own, because I know many of Nivens works.

Comment: @user14111 it would be far better if someone posted an answer and the OP accepted it

Comment: @user14111 Because it leaves a paper trail that is permanent. No one in the future, be it bot or human could go around cleaning up an answer that is accepted without it being visible to large portions of the community or entirely reversible. A comment however can be deleted by a single click by certain users, or by a bot programmed to search for specific comments and either having it trigger it's threshold or catching a false positive.